# Powershell Internet Explorer Automation

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

Trying to get powershell to start different websites at some time intervals.

Here is a script that works:

```
function IEWeb {

    $ie = New-Object -Comobject 'InternetExplorer.Application'
    $ie.visible=$true

    Do
    {
        $ie.navigate('http://p-captas02.int.addom.dk/cap-tas-views/Queue.aspx')
        start-sleep 15

        $ie.navigate('https://oneview.int.addom.dk/dashboard?dashboard_id=1')
        start-sleep 15

        $ie.navigate('https://oneview.int.addom.dk/dashboard?time=0&scroll_value=15&dashboard_id=10')
        start-sleep 15
    } 

    While ($ie.name -contains 'Internet Explorer') 

}#Function
```

The problem is that it does not work every time

Is there anyone who knows another way of doing it?

It is important that the websites are started in the same tab

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work every time"? Do you mean that it doesn't open IE, doesn't load the _next_ page, skips pages, etc, etc?

You need to add some debug messages in your code e.g. `Write-Output "started do loop"`

Comment: IE, does not load the next page, it just stops and then no more happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better to check if IE has not been closed by the user at some point before trying to navigate to the next url. Also, `$ie.name` is a String, so `$ie.name -contains 'Internet Explorer'` would be wrong.

Maybe this works better for you.

```
function IEWeb {
    # create an array with the urls you want to revolve
    $urls = 'http://p-captas02.int.addom.dk/cap-tas-views/Queue.aspx',
            'https://oneview.int.addom.dk/dashboard?dashboard_id=1',
            'https://oneview.int.addom.dk/dashboard?time=0&scroll_value=15&dashboard_id=10'

    $ie = New-Object -Comobject 'InternetExplorer.Application'
    $ie.visible=$true

    $index = 0
    while ($ie.HWND) {   # for as long as the user does not close IE
        $ie.navigate($urls[$index])
        Start-Sleep 15
        # increment the array counter, and revert to index 0 if $urls length is reached
        $index = ($index + 1) % $urls.Count
    } 

    try {
        # close and release the Com object from memory
        $ie.Quit()
        [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ie) | Out-Null
        [System.GC]::Collect()
        [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    }
    catch {}
}

IEWeb
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it out as soon as possible!